# Griffon: running 'gradle build' - Execution failed for task ':jfxJar'

Tags: gradle, griffon

I am working on setting up a Griffon project on a clean install of OS X 10.9.4. I have been following the instructions in the Griffon Guide: http://new.griffon-framework.org/guide/latest/.

I successfully created a project using this lazybones command:

```
lazybones create griffon-javafx-groovy myApp
```

The project directory `myApp` was created successfully, using Griffon 2.0.0.RC2. Running `gradle run` works and displays the sample app window. However, running `gradle build` fails at the end with this message:

```
:jfxJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jfxJar'.
> com/oracle/tools/packager/Log
```

What could be causing this? It seems to not find the JavaFX packager. I believe everything, including the JDK8, is installed to the default locations. Let me know if additional info is needed.

Currently running:

```
Lazybones: 0.7.1
Gradle: 2.0
Groovy: 2.3.3
JVM: 1.8.0_11
OS: Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem with the same setup. Next I tried again with JDK 8u20 and the build succeeded. My guess is that 8u11 is missing some pieces as there's nothing on the Griffon side that changes the classpath used for the JFX packaging operations. Besides, 8u20 is more stable than 8u11.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Looking forward to developing with Griffon! Thanks so much for the quick answer, and for putting in the time to check it out. Many thanks.